# Accessing BCC with Inbound Email object

Tags: apex-email-service

We are using Email Services with a custom inbound email handler.  The inbound email object has fields to access the 'To:' and 'CC:' addresses in the email, but not 'BCC:'.  We have a situation where customers sometimes BCC one of our inbound email addresses.  But since there is no access to the BCC field, the custom handler cannot determine the BCC address being sent to.  Is there any workround for this?

Comment: Can you check the InboundEmail.Header[] if you can find the BCC address through `Received from` of that, though I am not sure

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work

Comment: then you can raise a question to Salesforce or otherwise wait for someone to chime in

Comment: Not a super convenient answer, but as a workaround, could you separate your inbound email addresses into their own email services? that way they'd have their own custom handler classes and you'd automatically know which address it was sent to. If you have lots of inbound addresses then obviously that wouldn't work well.